# Understanding Inequality Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am working on a problem with inequalities with intervals.

Find the positive number $M$ such that $|{x^3-2x^2+3x-4}|\le M$ for the interval $[-3,2]$.

How do I go about solving this problem. What is a good first approach in understanding what concepts are needed to be drawn to solve this exercise.

So far, I have had a look at graphing the function for the interval $[-3,2]$ and looked at the values of $y$ for the function. I have then looked at graphing $|{x^3-2x^2+3x-4}|$.

Comment: If you don't care about $M$ being the smallest such constant, then $\lvert x^3-2x^2+3x-4\rvert\leq\lvert x\rvert^3+2\lvert x\rvert^2+3\lvert x\rvert +4\leq 3^3+2\cdot 3^2+3\cdot 3+4=58$ works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^3-2x^2+3x-4$. Note that its derivative is always positive, meaning that it is an increasing function.

Using $f(-3)<0$ and $f(2)>0$, we know that there is an $\alpha\in[-3,2]$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$. Thus, the range of $|f(x)|$ for $x\in[-3,2]$ is $[0,\max\{f(-3),f(2)\}]$. This gives $M\ge\max\{f(-3),f(2)\}=58$.

This is a tight bound, since $58$ is achieved at $x=-3$.